# LVM: Removing physical volume

Tags: linux, lvm

I want to repartition my disk. My current partition table is as follows:

```
Disk /dev/vda: 1 TiB, 1136018849792 bytes, 2218786816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9039e337

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *         2048 224610303 224608256 107,1G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/vda2       224610304 226490367   1880064   918M 8e Linux LVM
```

I want to remove /dev/vda2 and extend /dev/vda1 up to fill the whole disk. Here is my current physical volumes status:

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/vda1
VG Name               vg0
PV Size               107,10 GiB / not usable 4,00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              27417
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          27417
PV UUID               XKfnoJ-VBxR-reLg-eE5n-h2yM-W5wt-RTbEcK

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/vda2
VG Name               vg0
PV Size               918,00 MiB / not usable 2,00 MiB
Allocatable           yes 
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              229
Free PE               229
Allocated PE          0
PV UUID               2xT1xt-wYCF-fDzm-f36Q-zeIc-xR0Y-Mf3sCo
```

Am I correct if I say that I can safely

```
vgreduce vg0 /dev/vda2
```

without pvmove-ing /dev/vda2 beforehand, because that physical volume is not being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pvmove` moves allocated PEs off a PV. There are no allocated PEs on /dev/vda2 so there is nothing to move. Yes you can safely run the `vgreduce` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove only unused physical volumes from a group. If you don't `pvmove` or `lvremove` all of the lvs on it, the `vgreduce` will give back only an error message.